# Describe query on a locked hive table hangs

Tags: hadoop, hive

Whenever hive table is locked in exclusive mode query to describe the same table hangs until lock is released. Is there a way to introduce a timeout after which describe query would just error out?

Answer (score 0):

Before executing `DESC <TABLE_NAME>` command, check lock status `SHOW LOCKS <TABLE_NAME>;`

```
If table is un-locked then
DESC <TABLE_NAME>
```

Comment: You are right, that is one approach. While this works there can be a few issues with this approach         1. Every time 'desc' command executed show locks is executed which can lead to performance issues in those cases when lock is not acquired by anyone.      2. There can be synchronization issues, i.e. after 'show locks' command is issued before executing the 'desc' command is executed some other application would acquire lock on the same table.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am providing workaround to avoid hang state. 1. SHOW LOCKS is light weight command and it better to have to avoid hangs until lock is released. 2. It has very less possibility that some other application would acquire lock between SHOW LOCKS and DESC. We can't help it, for thoses corner cases.

Comment: @Subrahmanya please make the answer as correct if it works for you